# error " property not found " in Delphi 2005

Tags: delphi, quickreports

After installing the QuickReport 5.0 version, I get property error messages on all Reports of my previous versions.The error message is FormName.Frame.Color: property not found.
Tried with removing all the properties of Frame but I need them. How do I solve this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanking you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use QuickReport. But the error typically indicates that a new version of a component on a form does not support a property anymore which was saved to the DFM with a previous version of the component. Usually a property was renamed or dropped. And if I say component I include frames on the form, too.

Usually you deal with it like this:

1. Open affected forms and accept the error which will remove the property from the DFM.
2. If you used the property in code you need to remove that, too. It will prevent compilation anyway.
3. Check the component docs and/or source to find out how the property is replaced (unless the feature was dropped completely).
4. Save the form.

Note that this problem can occur at runtime on any form which was not "fixed" like this.

Comment: After ignoring the error it removes the property, and I save it later.

Comment: Andy's DFM Check utility can be useful in these cases - see http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=177